# redraw function is redrawing not every object

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw

I have class "Player" with redraw method shown below. Also have class "Enemy" with the same method but fillStyle is changed to blue.

```
redraw(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.closePath();
}
```

then call them in function draw

```
function draw(){
    update()
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player.redraw();
    for (var enemy in enemies) {
        enemies[enemy].redraw();
    }
    for(var shot in shots){
        shots[shot].redraw();
    }

}
```

Player is drawn but enemies are not.(update method makes position recalculation and other stuff not tied to drawing on canvas).
Why?

Comment: Can you add something like `console.log("drawing", this)` to the method and check if it's called?

Comment: it is called.
`console.log('enemy redrawn on position' + this.posX.toString() + "  " + this.posY.toString());` is shown.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Have you checked the length of your enemies array? It could be empty.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/c84x3hej/ (I did rewrite it but it worked fine using your exact code)

Comment: don't know why, but changing rects to real sprites really worked!